# JQuery Mobile content height:100%

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application with JQuery Mobile.

[This](http://pastie.org/4297199) is my html code.

My page has a full-screen `<iframe>` inside. I have set the style `width:100%; height:100%; border:0%` for my `iframe` but it gives a height more than the content's height and scrollbar of main page appears.

How do I avoid this problem? (I want exactly `height:100%` for my `iframe`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all guys for answers!

Finally, I have found the solution. My solution is a little messy, but its OK.

This is my css:

```
    html,body{overflow-y:hidden}
    .frame {
        height: 100% ;
        width: 100% ;
        border: 0  ;
        background-color: green ;
    }

    .content {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .ui-content {
        margin: 0   !important ;
        padding: 0   !important ;
        border: 0   !important ;
        outline: 0   !important ;
        height: 100%  ;
        overflow: hidden  ;
    }
```

But if I use JQuery Mobile header, there will be an extra space (almost equal to header size.) Also It could be solved with the Javascript below :

```
function correctFrameSize() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.height = (window.innerHeight-40)+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the browser is setting a little margin and/or padding on the `body` and/or `html`.

Try [a classic CSS reset.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
```

Also, you can make sure the scrollbar doesn't appear by doing something like this:

```
html, body {overflow-y: hidden;}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: I added this code to my html, but nothing changed. Should I use `!important` for them??

Comment: @Mahdi You can add this CSS as a separate stylesheet included before your main styles.

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't need `!important` for anything. Make sure the CSS reset comes before the rest of your styles.

Comment: Oh! I thought it should be after the rest of my styles!

Comment: You *could* add it as a separate stylesheet, but I wouldn't. [Here's why.](http://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/)

Comment: Did you try `html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}`?

Comment: Didn't work. (overflow-y: hidden; was hides the scrollbar, but iframe still has more height than content)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14227/discussion-between-jezenthomas-and-mahdi)

Answer (score 1):

@Mahdi try this,

```
<iframe id="cnt" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>Your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>
```

**Hope this helps. :)**